# Does user input get copied on the stack beyond the space or null character if user input taken through strcpy()

Tags: python, c, assembly, gdb, stack-trace

I have a pretty basic doubt here.

Please consider the below sample C program being run on an Ubuntu 32 bit little endian machine.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf [8];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    system("/usr/bin/false");
}
```

Now I understand the security implications of the above code. Let us keep that aside for a while.

In the above code `buf` is a local variable. This means that the space for this buffer would be on the stack. Now we use `strcpy()` to copy user input onto the buffer. The user input itself is taken on the command line.

Now say the program is run with gdb as:

`gdb program`

Now if the user input is given to the program, from the gdb prompt, as :

> run `python -c "print 'A'*12 + '\x10\x83\x04\x08' + '\xda\x84\x04\x08'
>   + '\x24\xa0\x04\x08' + '\x62\x81\x04\x08' + '\x10\x83\x04\x08' + '\xda\x84\x04\x08' + '\x25\xa0\x04\x08' + '\xd8\x80\x04\x08' +
>   '\x10\x83\x04\x08' + '\xda\x84\x04\x08' + '\x26\xa0\x04\x08'  +
>   '\x13\x85\x04\x08' + '\x20\x83\x04\x08' + 'A'*4 +
>   '\x24\xa0\x04\x08';"`

the contents of the stack look like:

```
(gdb) x/20wx $esp
0xbffff5b0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x08048310
0xbffff5c0: 0x080484da  0x0804a024  0x08048162  0x08048310
0xbffff5d0: 0x080484da  0x0804a025  0x080480d8  0x08048310
0xbffff5e0: 0x080484da  0x0804a026  0x08048513  0x08048300
0xbffff5f0: 0x00000000  0x6fb0e3f2  0x53b687e2  0x00000000
```

The word on extreme right hand side at the address `0xbffff5e0` is `0x08048300`. It should have been `0x08048320` as per the input given.

Why is it not as expected ? One thing that strikes me is that the expected address `0x08048320` ends with a `20` which is a space character. Could it be possible that because it's a space character being passed as input to the program, it is considered as end of input by the program and hence it does not copy anything beyond that at all ?

Comment: The contents of the stack **at which point**?

Comment: How are you running the program?! Yes, the space can separate command line arguments as you very well know. If you knew this, why didn't you try **21** at that position?

Comment: with 21 it works fine. But what I am not able to clearly comprehend is that as far as *argv is concerned, as soon as it sees a space in the input, it just considers that as the end of input ? How does that at all happen ? If that is at all what happens.

Comment: because **GDB** will split your string into 2 command line arguments.

Comment: and to make a mention of why 21 was not used in it's place is because the above is just a oversimplified version of the actual problem and it did not make any sense to dump out all that unnecessary info here.

Comment: Also please fix the formatting of your question, so that it is clear what is being executed here

Comment: is it *GDB* that is in fact doing this or is it something else ? I doubt it is GDB because even if the program is run normally from the command line without GDB, the results are still the same. So it tends me to believe it is not GDB but something else, perhaps the way command line arguments are processed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162329/discussion-between-qre0ct-and-antti-haapala).

Comment: [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: shouldn buf be optimized away as dead code?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thank you sir. One link that makes it absolutely clear as to what is going on ! **Awesome reply**

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `strcpy()` will stop copying when it hits a null, and that it will append a null to what is copied.  What you are seeing here is not that.  The `0x20`, the space character, will not impact `strcpy()`, but it will be used as a significant character by the C runtime itself.

`char **argv`, as you know, is a pointer to a list of character arrays, each of which represents an argument from the command line.  Even though you are piping the data from Python and representing it there as hexadecimal data, as that is translated, you have a space in your data:  `'\x20\x83\x04\x08'`  For the C runtime processing arguments, this will break `0x08048320` into `0x08048300` since it will view the space as a delimiter.

To prove this is the case, take your python script and output the string to stdout rather than the pipeline.

Comment: "C runtime processing arguments"?  What?  This isn't DOS, the target process receives its args already split into `argv[]`, [as passed to `execve(2)` by the parent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).  GLIBC's / GCC's CRT startup code does not parse or re-parse this before passing it to `main`.  I think Antti is correct that GDB is doing word-splitting.  I think the OP is using backticks inside GDB, but they put it in a quote block instead of code formatting so the backticks are treated as markdown.